# How to create a project component / module in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have been studying JavaScript for the last couple of months, and the question is how to create a component or module without a framework.
It so happened that at first I was completely carried away by React and Vue, and only then I began to delve into my native language.
For example, we need to create a component module in which the form, submission and verification methods, some intermediate functions will be called, for example:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Proptypes from "prop-types";

// ACTIONS
import { login } from "../../store/actions/auth";

const Login = ({ login, isAuth }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const { email, password } = formData;

  const onChange = (e) =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login({ email, password });
  };

  return (
    <form className="form" onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email Address"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          name="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
        />
      </div>
      <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
    </form>
  );
};

Login.propTypes = {
  login: Proptypes.func.isRequired,
  isAuth: Proptypes.bool,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuth: state.auth.isAuth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login })(Login);
```

Above, I create a Login component in which there is a form, events that we fire outside of jsx markup (onChange, onSubmit) are attached to the form and to the inputs ...
As part of the React, everything is logical and understandable, how to work with components, how to handle events, etc.

The question is how to implement such a module in your native language?
I understand that you can do this:
1) Create a component:

```js
class Login {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    const { email, phone, password } = this.state;
    const formData = {
      email,
      phone,
      password,
    };
    console.log(formData);
  }

  isLoading() {
    return !this.state.loading;
  }
}

export const loginForm = new Login();
```

2) Import it into the main file:

```js
import {signIN} from './module/SignIn';
```

3) Go to the elements on the page, bind events and call methods here:

```js
import {loginForm} from './module/SignIn';


const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input-form');
const form = document.querySelector('.form');

inputs.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    loginForm.onChange(e)
  })
});


form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  loginForm.onSubmit(e)
})
```

I understand that you can bind elements in the module constructor, but it seems that they are not ...
How to approach the implementation of such components? (interested in the approach and architecture).
Please help me!

Comment: Not sure this is on topic here, likely answers will be opinionated. E.g. `this.state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;` is likley not a good idea, given that *name* must match a value that's hard coded in the constructor. It's just not necessary to store data like that - but that's just my opinion.